# Is it possible to find the value of $x$ where $e^x$ exceeds $x^{10}$ by hand?

Tags: functions, polynomials, exponential-function

All I managed is to "simplify" the equation $e^x=x^{10}$ to $\frac{x}{\ln{x}}=10$. Is there some way or trick to make the equation look like $x=\dots$? (Solve the equation, in other words.)

Comment: Taylor expansion?

Comment: @MonkeyKing I am not yet familiar with that, unfortunately.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: "Is there some way or trick...?" : No. The Lambert W function does not solve your problem; it just gives it a name.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you want the positive solution.  Write the equation as $f(x) = 0$ where $f(x) = e^{x/10} - x$.  A good initial guess is $x_0 = 1$.
Newton's method is the iteration
$$ x_{n+1} = x - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \dfrac{e^{x/10} (10 - x)}{10 - e^{x/10}}$$
You get $x_1 \approx 1.118238267$, $x_2 \approx 1.118325592$, and $x_3$ is the same (to 10 significant digits).  So the solution is approximately
$1.118325592$.

Answer (score 3):

Even more simply:

You want to find $x$ such that
$x = e^{x/10}$.
For small $x$,
$e^{x/10}
\sim 1+x/10
$,
so, 
approximately,
$x \sim 1+x/10$
or
$x \sim 10/9 = 1.111...$.

If $f(x) = e^{x/10}$,
$f'(x)
=e^{x/10}/10
\sim (1.111...)/10 
< 1
$,
so the iteration
$ x \gets f(x) 
$
should converge.

And the iterations,
starting at $10/9$,
are
$1.1175190687,
1.1182353997,
1.1183155052,
1.1183244636,
1.1183254654
$
and it is,
as expected,
converging.

Of course
Newton's method,
as in Robert Israel's answer,
converges faster.
(From what I have seen,
his mind converges much faster
than mine, also.)